# I need to refresh my page to update the text-area, even though I set the text the same way as before

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>ZET</title>
        <?php
        $text = file_get_contents("text.txt");
        file_put_contents("text.txt", $_POST["file"]);
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", submit);

            function submit() {
                document.getElementById("submit").submit();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById("text").value = "<?php echo $text ?>"
                }, 1000);
            }
            loop();

            function loop() {
                document.getElementById("textpost").value = document.getElementById("text").value;
                setTimeout(loop, 50)
            }
            document.getElementById("text").value = "<?php echo $text ?>"
        }

        submit.onclick = function () {
            location.reload(true);
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id="text"></textarea>
        <div id="tools">
            <div id="save"></div>
            <form action="index.php" method=POST id="submit">
                <input id="textpost" type="text" name="file">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The above code is my HTML/PHP/JAVASCRIPT**

```
text {
   position: fixed;
   left: 350px;
   top: 0px;
   background-color: #ADD8E6;
   border: none;
}

#submit {
   background-color: #B4B7B0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
}

#tools {
   position: fixed;
   top: 25px;
   left: 25px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 300px;
}

#textpost {
   visibility: hidden;
}

#save {
   width: 100%;
   height: 25px;
   background-color: black;
}
```

**The above code is my CSS**

When I first load the page, it loads the text document into the textarea just how I wanted, but when I try to update the text later after submitting it, (The text reverts for some reason.) it doesn't work and I have to refresh the page.
I don't know why this happens, and have had to rewrite the entire thing several times messing around with it (I am very new to PHP).

**(This is hosted with Apache using XAMPP on localhost)**

**(The file text.txt is just random text I can edit with this.)**

Comment: textarea is a form input, so it needs to be inside the form tags. Also the textarea needs a `name="file"` in order to populate $_POST['file']   You can do `print_r($_POST);` to see what your form is sending.

Comment: also.. <?php echo $text; ?>    you need to end commands with a semi-colon  `;`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice those missing semi-colons and I didn't know text-area was a form input, so I was assigning a input box to the text in the textarea.

Comment: That's because you are first reading the content of the text file and then writing the content of the `<textarea>` in the text file. so when you submit the form and page refreshes, first the old content of the _text.txt_ will be loaded and then your changes will be written in the file. that's why when you refresh the page for the second time, you get the new content. also you have some logical problem in your JavaScript code!

Comment: Thanks! That should've been more obvious to me ._.

Comment: :) you are welcome...

Answer (score 1):

**Please check below this code perfect running.**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>ZET</title>
    <?php @file_put_contents("text.txt", $_POST["file"]); ?>
    <?php $text = file_get_contents("text.txt"); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", submit);
    function submit() {
    document.getElementById("submit").submit();
    setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("text").value = "<?php echo $text ?>"
    }, 1000);
    }
    loop();
    function loop() {
    document.getElementById("textpost").value = document.getElementById("text").value;
    setTimeout(loop, 50)
    }
    document.getElementById("text").value = "<?php echo $text ?>"
    }
    submit.onclick = function() {
    location.reload(true);
    }
    </script>



 <!--Css code -->
    <style>
    text {
    position: fixed;
    left: 350px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    border: none;
    }

    #submit {
    background-color: #B4B7B0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    }

    #tools {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    }

    #textpost {
    visibility: hidden;
    }

    #save {
    width: 100%;
    height:25px;
    background-color: black;
    }   
    </style>
    <!-- Css code end -->

    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <div id="tools">
    <div id="save"></div>
    <form action="index2.php" method=POST id="submit">
    <input id="textpost" type="text" name="file">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and try to add some details to your answer and describe to OP what was the origin of the problem and how you solved it. Also you code really hurt my eyes. Please try to format your code properly so it will be easy to read...